# redirect console log to verbatimTextOutput and autoscroll to the bottom with custom css

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinyjs

given a verbatimTextOutput("consoleOutput") in the ui of a shiny app, what is needed to redirect the console log output to the verbatimTextOutput, autoscroll to the bottom when a new message is sent and use a custom css file?

Answer (score 0):

in order to send console logs from a shiny app we'll need shinyjs, for example: logjs("test console log").

Once it's installed follow this steps

1. go to www and create a folder named "js"
2. inside the js folder create a file named console.js
3. put the following code inside:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var consoleOutput = $('#consoleOutput');

  console.log = function(message) {
    var timestamp = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    consoleOutput.append('<p>' + timestamp + ' - ' + message + '</p>');
    consoleOutput.scrollTop(consoleOutput.prop("scrollHeight"));
  }
});
```

4. go to www and create a folder named "css"
5. inside the css folder create a file named style.css
6. put the following code inside (change it as you like):

```css
#consoleOutput {
  padding: 9px 12px 7px;
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: inherit;
  height: 15em;
}
```

7. inside the ui of your shiny app add the following code:

```R
# Set up shinyjs 
useShinyjs(),
    
# Head tags
tags$head(
  tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "css/style.css"),
  tags$script(src = "js/console.js"),
),
```